# Create download link in CGrid view Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. I am having a form by which user submits some information including files. Files are stored in my images directory ... Now what I want is create a link in my VIEW to download the uploaded file .
    View code

```
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('Resume')); ?>:</b>
        <? echo CHtml::link($data,array('displaySavedImage','id'=>$model->id)); ?>

controller

public function actionDisplaySavedImage()
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($_GET['id']);

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-length: '.$model->file_size);
    header('Content-Type: '.$model->file_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$model->file_name);

        echo $model->file_content;
}
```

Comment: the line with `echo CHtml::link` starts with `<? echo`, but should start with `<?php echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile('filename', file_get_contents('path to your image'));

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#sendFile-detail